# Get All Windows between Start and End Dates

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2017

Here is the SQL Fiddle for my question:  https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=ab1634d7-fec7-4918-ac1c-3f4fcac8dc92

I have the following sample data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Price
CREATE TABLE #Price (DataId INT IDENTITY(1,1), NameOfWidget VARCHAR(50), Price MONEY, PriceScheduleId INT, 
                     StartEffectiveWhen DATE, EndEffectiveWhen DATE)

INSERT INTO #Price (NameOfWidget, Price, PriceScheduleId, StartEffectiveWhen, EndEffectiveWhen)
VALUES
    ('CoolWidget', 3.51, 1, '2015-1-1', '2021-12-31'),
    ('CoolWidget', 2.00, 2, '2017-1-1', '2022-12-31'),
    ('CoolWidget', 4.23, 1, '2021-1-1', '2100-12-31'),
    ('CoolWidget', 2.00, 2, '2021-1-1', '2100-12-31'),
    ('OtherWidget', 13.24, 1, '2014-1-1', '2100-12-31')
```

I now need to get this data into the following format:

```
NameOfWidget    StartEffectiveWhen  EndEffectiveWhen
CoolWidget      2015-01-01          2016-12-31
CoolWidget      2017-01-01          2021-12-31
CoolWidget      2021-01-01          2022-12-31
CoolWidget      2023-01-01          2100-12-31
OtherWidget     2015-01-01          2100-12-31
```

This follows the following logic, grouped by `NameOfWidget`:

1. Finds the lowest `StartEffectiveWhen`.
2. Finds the next lowest `StartEffectiveWhen` or `EndEffectiveWhen`.  That date becomes the next `EndEffectiveWhen`.  But if it was an `EndEffectiveWhen`, then we subtract one day from it.
3. It then repeats the above steps, except it excludes the already used data.

The goal is to have a row for each and every time frame "window".

The code below does what I need, but it uses a loop to do it.

As usual, my real data is much more complex.  It also has 56 million rows.  (The code below takes 3 hours to run on my real data)

**I am hoping for a way to do what I have below without needing to loop.**

---

### My (Slow, Loop Based) Code

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #EffectiveRange
CREATE TABLE #EffectiveRange (EffectiveDateId INT IDENTITY(1,1), StartEffectiveWhen DATE, EndEffectiveWhen DATE, EndWhenOfRowsThatMatchStartDate DATE, SecondStartWhen DATE, NameOfWidget VARCHAR(50), CalculationRound INT)

DECLARE @CalculationRound INT = 1

-- This is < 15 in my real code
WHILE (@CalculationRound < 5)
BEGIN

    -- Find the first/next range in source price table.
    INSERT INTO  #EffectiveRange(StartEffectiveWhen, EndWhenOfRowsThatMatchStartDate, SecondStartWhen, NameOfWidget, CalculationRound)
    SELECT  MIN(price.StartEffectiveWhen) StartWhen, NULL, NULL, price.NameOfWidget, @CalculationRound
    FROM    #Price price            
    WHERE   price.StartEffectiveWhen > 
            (SELECT MAX(maxValue.StartWhen) 
             FROM 
                (SELECT MAX(rangesSub.StartEffectiveWhen) AS StartWhen
                 FROM   #EffectiveRange AS rangesSub
                 WHERE  rangesSub.NameOfWidget = price.NameOfWidget
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT CAST('1/1/1900' AS DATE) AS StartWhen) AS maxValue)
    GROUP BY price.NameOfWidget 

    -- Find the end date for the rows that match the start date we just found.
    UPDATE  #EffectiveRange SET
       EndWhenOfRowsThatMatchStartDate = calc.EndWhenOfRowsThatMatchStartDateCalc
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT  MIN(price.EndEffectiveWhen) AS EndWhenOfRowsThatMatchStartDateCalc, price.NameOfWidget
            FROM    #Price price
                    JOIN #EffectiveRange ranges
                        ON ranges.NameOfWidget = price.NameOfWidget
                        AND ranges.CalculationRound = @CalculationRound
            WHERE   price.StartEffectiveWhen = ranges.StartEffectiveWhen
            GROUP BY price.NameOfWidget
        ) AS calc
        JOIN #EffectiveRange ranges
            ON ranges.NameOfWidget = calc.NameOfWidget
            AND ranges.CalculationRound = @CalculationRound

    -- Find the next largest start date for the calculation round.        
    UPDATE  #EffectiveRange SET
        SecondStartWhen = calc.SecondStartWhen
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT  MIN(price.StartEffectiveWhen) SecondStartWhen, price.NameOfWidget
            FROM    #Price price
                    JOIN #EffectiveRange ranges
                        ON ranges.NameOfWidget = price.NameOfWidget
                        AND ranges.CalculationRound = @CalculationRound
            WHERE   price.StartEffectiveWhen > ranges.StartEffectiveWhen
            GROUP BY price.NameOfWidget
        ) AS calc
        JOIN #EffectiveRange ranges
            ON ranges.NameOfWidget = calc.NameOfWidget
            AND ranges.CalculationRound = @CalculationRound

    -- Send the EndWhen to be the lesser of EndWhenOfRowsThatMatchStartDate and secondStartDate.  
    -- This will define our window of effectiveness for this round of the test. (once we have all of the windows (aka each time a change was made),
    -- we will caclulate the price for each window.
    UPDATE #EffectiveRange SET
        EndEffectiveWhen = IIF((EndWhenOfRowsThatMatchStartDate < SecondStartWhen) OR SecondStartWhen IS NULL, EndWhenOfRowsThatMatchStartDate, DATEADD(DAY, -1, SecondStartWhen))
    WHERE   CalculationRound = @CalculationRound

    SET @CalculationRound = @CalculationRound + 1
END

-- Show the final result
SELECT  ranges.NameOfWidget, ranges.StartEffectiveWhen, ranges.EndEffectiveWhen
FROM    #EffectiveRange ranges
ORDER BY ranges.NameOfWidget, ranges.StartEffectiveWhen


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #EffectiveRange
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Price
```

---

### Update

This SQL Fiddle shows what I ended up doing:

https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=b0d81632-b14d-4374-a80e-0835750f48bc

@Akina got me thinking about my issue in the right direction.  (Thanks @Akina!)

Just incase, here is the query that I ended up using:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Price
CREATE TABLE #Price (DataId INT IDENTITY(1,1), NameOfWidget VARCHAR(50), Price MONEY, PriceScheduleId INT, StartEffectiveWhen DATE, EndEffectiveWhen DATE)

INSERT INTO #Price (NameOfWidget, Price, PriceScheduleId, StartEffectiveWhen, EndEffectiveWhen)
VALUES
    ('CoolWidget', 3.51, 1, '2015-1-1', '2021-12-31'),
    ('CoolWidget', 2.00, 2, '2017-1-1', '2022-12-31'),
    ('CoolWidget', 4.23, 1, '2021-1-1', '2100-12-31'),
    ('CoolWidget', 2.00, 2, '2021-1-1', '2100-12-31'),
    ('OtherWidget', 13.24, 1, '2014-1-1', '2018-5-4'),
    ('OtherWidget', 13.24, 1, '2018-5-6', '2019-12-31'),
    ('OtherWidget', 13.24, 1, '2020-1-1', '2100-12-31')

;WITH OrderedDates AS 
(
    SELECT  priceStart.NameOfWidget, priceStart.StartEffectiveWhen AS DateWhen, 1 AS IsStartDate, 0 AS IsEndDate
    FROM    #Price priceStart

    UNION 

    SELECT  priceStart.NameOfWidget, priceStart.EndEffectiveWhen AS DateWhen, 0 AS IsStartDate, 1 AS IsEndDate
    FROM    #Price priceStart
    
)
SELECT  OrderedDates.NameOfWidget,
        CASE 
            WHEN LAG(OrderedDates.DateWhen) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderedDates.NameOfWidget ORDER BY OrderedDates.DateWhen) IS NULL THEN '1900-1-1'
            WHEN LAG(OrderedDates.IsStartDate ) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderedDates.NameOfWidget ORDER BY OrderedDates.DateWhen) = 1 
                THEN  LAG(OrderedDates.DateWhen) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderedDates.NameOfWidget ORDER BY OrderedDates.DateWhen)
            ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 1, LAG(OrderedDates.DateWhen) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderedDates.NameOfWidget ORDER BY OrderedDates.DateWhen))
        END AS StartEffectiveWhen, 
        
        CASE
            WHEN OrderedDates.IsEndDate = 1 THEN OrderedDates.DateWhen
            ELSE DATEADD(DAY, -1, OrderedDates.DateWhen)
        END AS EndEffectiveWhen
FROM    OrderedDates
ORDER BY OrderedDates.NameOfWidget
```

Comment: Please explain where `StartEffectiveWhen = '2023-01-01'` is taken from within your desired output? Maybe, there is a misprint in your source data, and `StartEffectiveWhen = '2021-1-1'` must be `'2023-01-01'` in 4th source row?

Comment: It comes from either row with start '2021-1-1' and end '2100-12-31'. The idea is that there is an ongoing “window”. So when the '2022-12-31' end date happens, we need to start a up a span of time from the day after the one before ended til the end of the window (‘2100-12-31’)

Comment: *So when the '2022-12-31' end date happens, we need to start a up a span of time ..* ??? Sorry, I have read your words a lot of times, but they are not clear to me. It seems that your '2022-12-31' must be cut off by start value '2021-1-1'.

Comment: @Vaccano if you have an answer to your own question, you should add it as an answer. Putting answers in questions gets the moderators prickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT NameOfWidget,
       StartEffectiveWhen,
       CASE WHEN EndEffectiveWhen >= LEAD(StartEffectiveWhen) OVER (PARTITION BY NameOfWidget ORDER BY StartEffectiveWhen) 
            THEN DATEADD(day, -1, LEAD(StartEffectiveWhen) OVER (PARTITION BY NameOfWidget ORDER BY StartEffectiveWhen))
            ELSE EndEffectiveWhen
            END EndEffectiveWhen
FROM #Price t1
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

| NameOfWidget | StartEffectiveWhen | EndEffectiveWhen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CoolWidget | 2015-01-01 | 2016-12-31 |
| CoolWidget | 2017-01-01 | 2020-12-31 |
| CoolWidget | 2021-01-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| CoolWidget | 2023-01-01 | 2100-12-31 |
| OtherWidget | 2014-01-01 | 2100-12-31 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cAk5ggD9)

PS. Source data is fixed, `('CoolWidget', 2.00, 2, '2021-1-1', '2100-12-31')` is altered to `('CoolWidget', 2.00, 2, '2023-1-1', '2100-12-31')`.

Comment: While this did not do what I needed, it got me on the right path.  The `LEAD` with `OVER` was what I needed to get the solution I was looking for.  See my updated question for the answer that worked for me.